# Entity Framework Code First : Can I always eager load dependencies of one entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to improve something in my code using Entity Framework 6 (code first). I have the following model classes (only important classes included) :

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public List<CourseRegistration> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public CourseType CourseType { get; set; }
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    public CourseDescription CourseDescription { get; set; }
}

public class CourseRegistration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public string Session { get; set; }
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

In my projet, I need to always get all the sub entities of the Course class. To do that, I can use the Include() method which work great :

```
IQueryable<Course> completeCourse = db.Courses
.Include(r => r.CourseType)
.Include(r => r.CourseDescription)
.Include(r => r.Department)
.Include(r => r.Teacher);
```

Now here's the problem. When I query courses from CourseRegistration, I still need to include all the sub entities but the syntax is a bit different:

```
IQueryable<CourseRegistration> registrations = db.CourseRegistrations
.Include(r => r.Course)
.Include(r => r.Course.CourseDescription)
.Include(r => r.Course.CourseType)
.Include(r => r.Course.Department)
.Include(r => r.Course.Teacher)
.Include(r => r.Student)
.Include(r => r.Results);
```

It's not really DRY. I'm looking for a way to make sure a Course class will always be fully loaded no matter what's the source of the query.Does someone know a way I could "chain" the Includes required for my Course class to any query ?

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you would need to do this in the modelbuilder, but according to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/6837712/1026459 it is not possible. Perhaps you could use a custom get;set; configuration to work with a Queryable and return the loaded set, but I am not sure how that would be accomplished or if the Queryable is even available in that context.

Comment: Have you looked into [Lazy Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)?  It's less efficient at runtime, but it can dramatically simplify the code.

Comment: I know it can be achieved with lazy loading but in this particular case, I would want to avoid it because, as said by Travis J, I still need a context for that and I don't have it when I use the data.